# cfncluster returns an error when I use spot instances for compute fleet

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to make HPC using AWS cfncluster.
If I make ondemand fleet for compute nodes, it works fine.
But when I try to use spot fleet, it returned an error.

Here is my config template.

```
[aws]
aws_region_name = us-east-2

[cluster default]
vpc_settings = public
key_name = *********
compute_instance_type = c4.8xlarge
master_instance_type = m4.xlarge
initial_queue_size = 2
max_queue_size = 10
maintain_initial_size = false
cluster_type = spot
spot_price = 1.60
master_root_volume_size = 20
base_os = centos7
ebs_settings = custom

[vpc public]
master_subnet_id = subnet-*******
vpc_id = vpc-*********

[ebs custom]
volume_type = io1
volume_iops = 2000
volume_size = 2000
encrypted = true

[global]
update_check = true
sanity_check = true
cluster_template = default
```

And the occurred error in CloudForamtion

```
23:54:01 UTC+0900   DELETE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::EC2::EIPAssociation    AssociateEIP    
23:53:56 UTC+0900   ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS    AWS::CloudFormation::Stack  cfncluster-test3    The following resource(s) failed to create: [ComputeFleet]. . Rollback requested by user.
23:53:55 UTC+0900   CREATE_FAILED   AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup  ComputeFleet    Received 0 SUCCESS signal(s) out of 2. Unable to satisfy 100% MinSuccessfulInstancesPercent requirement
23:53:54 UTC+0900   UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup  ComputeFleet    Failed to receive 2 resource signal(s) for the current batch. Each resource signal timeout is counted as a FAILURE.
23:23:53 UTC+0900   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS  AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup  ComputeFleet    Resource creation Initiated
```

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42604753/aws-cloudformation-stack-fails-with-error-received-0-success-signals-out-of-1