# AWS Autoscaled EC2 instance failing to launch with cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, autoscaling

I am trying to launch Autoscaling EC2 instance from cloudformation and below is my cloudformation. i am getting error as

> Received 0 SUCCESS signal(s) out of 1. Unable to satisfy 100% MinSuccessfulInstancesPercent requirement.

and after i get this error stack is rolling back and deleting all the resources.

```html
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",

  "Description": "AWS CloudFormation Sample Template AutoScalingRollingUpdates: Create a load balanced, Auto Scaled sample website. This example creates an Auto Scaling group behind a load balancer with a simple health check. The AutoScaling launch configuration includes an update policy that will keep 2 instances running while doing an autoscaling rolling upgrade. **WARNING** This template creates one or more Amazon EC2  instances and an Application Load Balancer. You will be billed for the AWS resources used if you create a stack from this template.",

  "Parameters": {
    "VpcId" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::VPC::Id",
      "Description" : "VpcId of your existing Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)",
      "ConstraintDescription" : "must be the VPC Id of an existing Virtual Private Cloud."
    },
  
    "Subnets" : {
      "Type" : "List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>",
      "Description" : "The list of SubnetIds in your Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)",
      "ConstraintDescription" : "must be a list of at least two existing subnets associated with at least two different availability zones. They should be residing in the selected Virtual Private Cloud."
    },

    "InstanceType": {
      "Description": "WebServer EC2 instance type",
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "t2.nano",
      "AllowedValues": [ "t1.micro", "t2.nano", "t2.micro", "t2.small", "t2.medium", "t2.large", "m1.small", "m1.medium", "m1.large", "m1.xlarge", "m2.xlarge", "m2.2xlarge", "m2.4xlarge", "m3.medium", "m3.large", "m3.xlarge", "m3.2xlarge", "m4.large", "m4.xlarge", "m4.2xlarge", "m4.4xlarge", "m4.10xlarge", "c1.medium", "c1.xlarge", "c3.large", "c3.xlarge", "c3.2xlarge", "c3.4xlarge", "c3.8xlarge", "c4.large", "c4.xlarge", "c4.2xlarge", "c4.4xlarge", "c4.8xlarge", "g2.2xlarge", "g2.8xlarge", "r3.large", "r3.xlarge", "r3.2xlarge", "r3.4xlarge", "r3.8xlarge", "i2.xlarge", "i2.2xlarge", "i2.4xlarge", "i2.8xlarge", "d2.xlarge", "d2.2xlarge", "d2.4xlarge", "d2.8xlarge", "hi1.4xlarge", "hs1.8xlarge", "cr1.8xlarge", "cc2.8xlarge", "cg1.4xlarge"]
,
      "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid EC2 instance type."
    },

    "KeyName": {
      "Description": "Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the instances",
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName",
      "ConstraintDescription" : "must be the name of an existing EC2 KeyPair."
    },

    "SSHLocation" : {
      "Description" : "The IP address range that can be used to SSH to the EC2 instances",
      "Type": "String",
      "MinLength": "9",
      "MaxLength": "18",
      "Default": "0.0.0.0/0",
      "AllowedPattern": "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})",
      "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x."
    }
  },

  "Mappings": {
    "Region2Examples" : {
      "us-east-1"      : { "Examples" : "https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples-us-east-1" },
      "us-west-2"      : { "Examples" : "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples-us-west-2" },
      "us-west-1"      : { "Examples" : "https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples-us-west-1" },
      "eu-west-1"      : { "Examples" : "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples-eu-west-1" },
      "eu-west-2"      : { "Examples" : "https://s3-eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples-eu-west-2" },
      "eu-central-1"   : { "Examples" : "https://s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples-eu-central-1" },
      "ap-southeast-1" : { "Examples" : "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples-ap-southeast-1" },
      "ap-northeast-1" : { "Examples" : "https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples-ap-northeast-1" },
      "ap-northeast-2" : { "Examples" : "https://s3-ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples-ap-northeast-2" },
      "ap-southeast-2" : { "Examples" : "https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples-ap-southeast-2" },
      "ap-south-1"     : { "Examples" : "https://s3-ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples-ap-south-1" },
      "us-east-2"      : { "Examples" : "https://s3-us-east-2.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples-us-east-2" },
      "ca-central-1"   : { "Examples" : "https://s3-ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples-ca-central-1" },
      "sa-east-1"      : { "Examples" : "https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples-sa-east-1" },
      "cn-north-1"     : { "Examples" : "https://s3.cn-north-1.amazonaws.com.cn/cloudformation-examples-cn-north-1" }
    }
,
    "AWSInstanceType2Arch" : {
      "t1.micro"    : { "Arch" : "PV64"   },
      "t2.nano"     : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "t2.micro"    : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "t2.small"    : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "t2.medium"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "t2.large"    : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "m1.small"    : { "Arch" : "PV64"   },
      "m1.medium"   : { "Arch" : "PV64"   },
      "m1.large"    : { "Arch" : "PV64"   },
      "m1.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "PV64"   },
      "m2.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "PV64"   },
      "m2.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "PV64"   },
      "m2.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "PV64"   },
      "m3.medium"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "m3.large"    : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "m3.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "m3.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "m4.large"    : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "m4.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "m4.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "m4.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "m4.10xlarge" : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "c1.medium"   : { "Arch" : "PV64"   },
      "c1.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "PV64"   },
      "c3.large"    : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "c3.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "c3.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "c3.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "c3.8xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "c4.large"    : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "c4.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "c4.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "c4.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "c4.8xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "g2.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVMG2"  },
      "g2.8xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVMG2"  },
      "r3.large"    : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "r3.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "r3.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "r3.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "r3.8xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "i2.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "i2.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "i2.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "i2.8xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "d2.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "d2.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "d2.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "d2.8xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "hi1.4xlarge" : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "hs1.8xlarge" : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "cr1.8xlarge" : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "cc2.8xlarge" : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  }
    },

    "AWSInstanceType2NATArch" : {
      "t1.micro"    : { "Arch" : "NATPV64"   },
      "t2.nano"     : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "t2.micro"    : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "t2.small"    : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "t2.medium"   : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "t2.large"    : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "m1.small"    : { "Arch" : "NATPV64"   },
      "m1.medium"   : { "Arch" : "NATPV64"   },
      "m1.large"    : { "Arch" : "NATPV64"   },
      "m1.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "NATPV64"   },
      "m2.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "NATPV64"   },
      "m2.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATPV64"   },
      "m2.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATPV64"   },
      "m3.medium"   : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "m3.large"    : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "m3.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "m3.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "m4.large"    : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "m4.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "m4.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "m4.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "m4.10xlarge" : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "c1.medium"   : { "Arch" : "NATPV64"   },
      "c1.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "NATPV64"   },
      "c3.large"    : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "c3.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "c3.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "c3.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "c3.8xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "c4.large"    : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "c4.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "c4.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "c4.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "c4.8xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "g2.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVMG2"  },
      "g2.8xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVMG2"  },
      "r3.large"    : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "r3.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "r3.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "r3.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "r3.8xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "i2.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "i2.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "i2.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "i2.8xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "d2.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "d2.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "d2.4xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "d2.8xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "hi1.4xlarge" : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "hs1.8xlarge" : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "cr1.8xlarge" : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  },
      "cc2.8xlarge" : { "Arch" : "NATHVM64"  }
    }
,
    "AWSRegionArch2AMI" : {
      "us-east-1"        : {"PV64" : "ami-2a69aa47", "HVM64" : "ami-00068cd7555f543d5", "HVMG2" : "ami-035240afa793cddbb"},
      "us-west-2"        : {"PV64" : "ami-7f77b31f", "HVM64" : "ami-7172b611", "HVMG2" : "ami-60aa3700"},
      "us-west-1"        : {"PV64" : "ami-a2490dc2", "HVM64" : "ami-31490d51", "HVMG2" : "ami-4b694d2b"},
      "eu-west-1"        : {"PV64" : "ami-4cdd453f", "HVM64" : "ami-f9dd458a", "HVMG2" : "ami-2955524f"},
      "eu-west-2"        : {"PV64" : "NOT_SUPPORTED", "HVM64" : "ami-886369ec", "HVMG2" : "NOT_SUPPORTED"},
      "eu-central-1"     : {"PV64" : "ami-6527cf0a", "HVM64" : "ami-ea26ce85", "HVMG2" : "ami-81ac71ee"},
      "ap-northeast-1"   : {"PV64" : "ami-3e42b65f", "HVM64" : "ami-374db956", "HVMG2" : "ami-46220c21"},
      "ap-northeast-2"   : {"PV64" : "NOT_SUPPORTED", "HVM64" : "ami-2b408b45", "HVMG2" : "NOT_SUPPORTED"},
      "ap-southeast-1"   : {"PV64" : "ami-df9e4cbc", "HVM64" : "ami-a59b49c6", "HVMG2" : "ami-c212aba1"},
      "ap-southeast-2"   : {"PV64" : "ami-63351d00", "HVM64" : "ami-dc361ebf", "HVMG2" : "ami-0ad2db69"},
      "ap-south-1"       : {"PV64" : "NOT_SUPPORTED", "HVM64" : "ami-ffbdd790", "HVMG2" : "ami-ca3042a5"},
      "us-east-2"        : {"PV64" : "NOT_SUPPORTED", "HVM64" : "ami-f6035893", "HVMG2" : "NOT_SUPPORTED"},
      "ca-central-1"     : {"PV64" : "NOT_SUPPORTED", "HVM64" : "ami-730ebd17", "HVMG2" : "NOT_SUPPORTED"},
      "sa-east-1"        : {"PV64" : "ami-1ad34676", "HVM64" : "ami-6dd04501", "HVMG2" : "NOT_SUPPORTED"},
      "cn-north-1"       : {"PV64" : "ami-77559f1a", "HVM64" : "ami-8e6aa0e3", "HVMG2" : "NOT_SUPPORTED"}
    }

  },

  "Resources": {
    "WebServerGroup": {
      "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
      "CreationPolicy" : {
        "ResourceSignal" : {
          "Timeout" : "PT5M",
          "Count"   : "1"
        }
      },
      "UpdatePolicy" : {
        "AutoScalingRollingUpdate" : {
          "MaxBatchSize" : "1",
          "MinInstancesInService" : "1",
          "PauseTime" : "PT15M",
          "WaitOnResourceSignals": "true"
        }
      },
      "Properties": {
        "VPCZoneIdentifier" : { "Ref" : "Subnets" },
        "LaunchConfigurationName": { "Ref": "LaunchConfig" },
        "MinSize": "1",
        "MaxSize": "1"        
      }
    },

    "LaunchConfig": {
      "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
      "Metadata" : {
        "Comment" : "Install a simple application",
        "AWS::CloudFormation::Init" : {
          "config" : {
            "packages" : {
              "yum" : {
                "httpd" : []
              }
            },

            "files" : {
              "/var/www/html/index.html" : {
                "content" : { "Fn::Join" : ["\n", [
                  "<img src=\"", {"Fn::FindInMap" : ["Region2Examples", {"Ref" : "AWS::Region"}, "Examples"]}, "/cloudformation_graphic.png\" alt=\"AWS CloudFormation Logo\"/>",
                  "<h1>Congratulations, you have successfully launched the AWS CloudFormation sample.</h1>"
                ]]},
                "mode"    : "000644",
                "owner"   : "root",
                "group"   : "root"
              },

              "/etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf" : {
                "content" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
                  "[main]\n",
                  "stack=", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackId" }, "\n",
                  "region=", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n"
                ]]},
                "mode"    : "000400",
                "owner"   : "root",
                "group"   : "root"
              },

              "/etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf" : {
                "content": { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
                  "[cfn-auto-reloader-hook]\n",
                  "triggers=post.update\n",
                  "path=Resources.LaunchConfig.Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init\n",
                  "action=/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v ",
                  "         --stack ", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" },
                  "         --resource LaunchConfig ",
                  "         --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n",
                  "runas=root\n"
                ]]}
              }
            },

            "services" : {
              "sysvinit" : {
                "httpd"    : { "enabled" : "true", "ensureRunning" : "true" },
                "cfn-hup" : { "enabled" : "true", "ensureRunning" : "true",
                              "files" : ["/etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf", "/etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf"]}
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "Properties": {
        "KeyName": { "Ref": "KeyName" },
        "ImageId": {
          "Fn::FindInMap": [ "AWSRegionArch2AMI", { "Ref": "AWS::Region" },
            { "Fn::FindInMap": [ "AWSInstanceType2Arch", { "Ref": "InstanceType" }, "Arch" ] } ]
        },
        "SecurityGroups": [ { "Ref": "InstanceSecurityGroup" } ],
        "InstanceType": { "Ref": "InstanceType" },
        "UserData"       : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
             "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
             "yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap\n",

             "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v ",
             "         --stack ", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" },
             "         --resource LaunchConfig ",
             "         --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n",

             "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? ",
             "         --stack ", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" },
             "         --resource WebServerGroup ",
             "         --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n"
        ]]}}
      }
    },
    
    "InstanceSecurityGroup": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "GroupDescription": "Enable SSH access and HTTP access on the configured port",
        "SecurityGroupIngress": [ 
          { "IpProtocol": "tcp", "FromPort": "22", "ToPort": "22", "CidrIp": { "Ref" : "SSHLocation" } },
          { "IpProtocol": "tcp", "FromPort": "80", "ToPort": "80", "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0" }
        ],
        "VpcId" : { "Ref" : "VpcId" }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

error screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please attach the error what instance states in the autoscaling group.
Did you referred this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42604753/aws-cloudformation-stack-fails-with-error-received-0-success-signals-out-of-1)

Answer (score 0):

The ASG is configured to require success signals.  This error means that the instances the ASG launched didn't send those messages back to CFN before the timeout (5 minutes since this was the initial stack creation)

Try increasing the timeout.  Also make sure the instances have internet access to be able to send the signal out